# Add weekly dates between years

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a requirement to get all the weekly dates between two years like

```
Today date is - 13th Sep 2021
After 3 years - 13th Sep 2024
```

So I need a collection of all the weekly dates between these two dates.

```
this.allSelectedRegions.push(date as any);
```

So how to achieve it.

Comment: Could you add the code you have tried? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `while` loop to keep adding dates until we reach the required end date. To add 7 days to a date we'll use `Date.getDate()` and `Date.setDate()`. This should also handle DST transitions.

```js
const startDate = new Date(2021, 8, 13);
const endDate = new Date(2024, 8, 13);

let date = startDate;
let result = [];
while (date <= endDate) {
    result.push(date);
    date = new Date(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
}

console.log('Results:', result.map(d => d.toDateString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var endDate = new Date(2024,8,13);
var startDate = new Date(2021,8,13);
var currentDate = startDate;
while(currentDate < endDate)
{
    document.getElementById("dateList").innerText += currentDate + "\n"; 
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7);
}
```

```html
<div id="dateList"></div>
```

Comment: classic off-by-1 error. (Javascript months are 0-based)

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for telling.. missed it